# Spring boot kafka junit is failing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am having a weird issue while trying my Junit to run with spring boot application. It is throwing fatal error exception on Kafka server startup.

Here is my JUnit

```
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.rule.KafkaEmbedded;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=SpringKafkaSenderTest.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class SpringKafkaSenderTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true, "foo");

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        template.send("foo", "bar");
        Thread.sleep(10_000);
    }
}
```

Here is my application-test.yaml

```
spring.profiles: test

spring:
  profiles:
    include: kafka
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    consumer:
      group-id: test
      enable-auto-commit: false
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    producer:
      acks: all
      retries: 3
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    listener:
      ack-mode: MANUAL
```

and it is throwing exception while trying to run this above Junit,
Here is my part of exception Log :

```
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.371 sec <<< FAILURE!
hello.SpringKafkaSenderTest  Time elapsed: 0.37 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/test/TestUtils
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.<init>(TestUtils.scala:70)
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.<clinit>(TestUtils.scala)
    at kafka.zk.EmbeddedZookeeper.<init>(EmbeddedZookeeper.scala:29)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.rule.KafkaEmbedded.startZookeeper(KafkaEmbedded.java:333)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.rule.KafkaEmbedded.before(KafkaEmbedded.java:175)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.test.TestUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more


Results :

Tests in error: 
  hello.SpringKafkaSenderTest: org/apache/kafka/test/TestUtils
```

**EDIT :**
Updated my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>1.5.10.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <kafka.version>0.11.0.0</kafka.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <spring-kafka.version>1.3.2.RELEASE</spring-kafka.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-kafka.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-kafka.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

What version of Boot? What version of spring-kafka? What version of spring-kafka-test? What version of kafka jars?

It looks like you have mismatched kafka jars on the classpath. `spring-kafka` and `spring-kafka-test` must be the same version, and `kafka-clients` and `kafka_2.11` must be the same version.

It looks like the `kafka_2.11` is 0.10.0.2 and `kafka-clients` is a different version.

Comment: `<kafka.version>0.11.0.0</kafka.version>`, `<spring-kafka.version>1.2.2.RELEASE</spring-kafka.version>`. You need `spring-kafla` 1.3.2 for `kafka-clients` 0.11.0.0. You also need to override `kafka-2.11` to 0.11.0.0. `<spring-boot.version>1.5.4.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>`. That is quite old; the current boot 1.5.x version is 1.5.10.

Comment: Hi @Gary Russell updated my pom, i am getting some other erros now :(
Am i missing something, sorry cant figure-out 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/test/TestUtils
 at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.<init>(TestUtils.scala:70)
 at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.<clinit>(TestUtils.scala)
 at kafka.zk.EmbeddedZookeeper.<init>(EmbeddedZookeeper.scala:29)

Comment: You still seem to have some serious dependency/classpath issues; that class is in the kafka-clients jar. Take a look at your maven dependency tree. If you can't figure it out, post your current pom.

Comment: i have already updated my current POM.xml & current error/exceptions above as per your recommendation, no Luck :(

Comment: I am not entirely sure what's going on, but removing the `<exclusions/>` from `spring-kafka-test` solved it for me. Some weirdness with the `kafka_2.11:test` jar.